# Can we make a line break on a "string_agg" Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, string-agg

I tried the method :

```
STRING_AGG(cast(client.nom as varchar(1000)), '
                ')
```

In order to produce a line break when exporting my query results to CSV.

This doesn't give me only one line break, but at least 5 for each record.

How to make a single line break between each record in a "string_agg" on PostgreSQL?

Thank you.

Comment: Try `string_agg(urgence.nom, chr(10))` - the cast is pretty much useless.

Comment: Perhaps there are a lot of empty strings in your table.

Comment: Thank you a_horse_with_no_name, indeed it works!
I followed your advice and deleted the cast, then indicated chr(10).

Comment: A CSV file does contain one linebreak between each row, and no other linebreaks. There is no way to change that, and nothing that `string_agg` needs to do about this. Can you show us how you are doing the CSV export, please?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `chr(10)` seems like a very obscure way to write `e'\n'`. Why would you prefer that?

Comment: @Bergi: because I "grew up" with that (e.g. in Oracle) and not the the `e'..'` notation ;)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Oh right I didn't realise that escape sequences are non-standard sql

Comment: @Bergi My problem was not with the csv but with the postgres "string_agg" formatting. This was solved with the method mentioned by a_horse_with_no_name.